# Is it possible to use console.log in CF code

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, console.log

Wondering if it is possible to use 'console.log' code within ColdFusion?

I have deployed the following code but to no effect:

```
  <cfif isDefined("placementCategoryID")>
                console.log('Placement Category ID is: ' + placementCategoryID);
                <cfif placementCategoryID GT 0>
```

and

```
<cfif isDefined("categoryDto")>
                                    console.log('Category DTO is: ' + categoryDto);
```

as examples but they do not seem to have the desired effect and results do not appear in dev tools window in Chrome.

Apologies if this is a bit of a basic question but any assistance would be appreciated.

Please note, due to customer being difficult, I do not want 'alerts' to pop up... Needs to be within console.log.

Comment: Your customer is not being difficult.  Unnecessary alerts are annoying and people running your applications should not be subjected to them.

Comment: I agree, I only added that in to prevent any 'Add an alert' comments :)

Answer (score 5):

Try wrapping your console.log code with `<script>` tags.

Edit: You'll also have to place # around your CF vars.

```
<cfif isDefined("placementCategoryID")>
    <script>
        <cfoutput>
        console.log('Placement Category ID is #placementCategoryID#');
        </cfoutput>
    </script>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Great Steve... I have added these in throughout my code... Just as a final question, I have a slightly different one i need to log... Would this be correct?

Comment: <cfset jobCategoryArray = wsFindJobCategories.getIds()>
                                 <script>
                                  <cfoutput>
                                  console.log('Job Categories returned are: #wsFindJobCategories#'.getIds());
                                  </cfoutput>
                                 </script>

Comment: No, that's not going to work. The CF array is not going to translate directly to javascript. You need to get a string representation of that array:

`<cfset jobCatetgoryList = arrayToList(jobCategoryArray) />`

Then console.log the jobCategoryList variable:

`console.log('Job Categories returned are: #jobCategoryList#')`

Comment: Wondering if I can just add as follows due to first line:

`                            <cfif isDefined("wsFindJobCategories")>
                                <cfset jobCategoryArray = ArrayNew(1)>
                                <cfset jobCategoryArray = wsFindJobCategories.getIds()>
                                 <script>
                                  <cfoutput>
                                  console.log('Job Categories returned are: #wsFindJobCategories#');
                                  </cfoutput>
                                 </script>`

Comment: Another way to output comolex ColdFusion objects to something compatible with the JavaScript console log would be to wrap the ColdFusion variable in `SerializeJSON()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more robust reporting, check out [coldfire](http://coldfire.riaforge.org/).

"ColdFire is an extension to Firebug. It provides debug information in a Firebug tab as opposed to the bottom of the page. This lets you debug and keep your site layout intact, since ColdFusion's built-in debug information can sometimes mess with your site layout."

Answer (score -1):

```
<cfif isDefined("placementCategoryID")>
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
      console.log("Placement Category ID is: "+<cfoutput>#placementCategoryID#</cfoutput>);
   </script>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.